# All class method call the element's method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which is A.

```py
class A:
 def __init__(self, ele):
    self.ele = ele
```

If I call A.fun(), I hope it can be converted to self.ele.fun().

I can't use inherit because I don't know the constructor of ele.

There are **many functions** in `ele` so I can't write each function separately.

Comment: You mean `A.fun()` should be a static method? Then you don't have a reference to `self` and can't do it.

Comment: Can you show a more complete example? If you're truly writing `A.fun()`, then at no point did you call the constructor, so `ele` doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method as a `getattr` wrapper to `self.ele` so that all undefined attribute accesses are deferred to `self.ele` instead. Note that this code pattern is known as defining a proxy object:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, ele):
        self.ele = ele

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.ele, name)
```

so that:

```
print(A('foo bar').split())
```

outputs:

```
['foo', 'bar']
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/7H9tT5

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't call ele methods from A Classes objects unless you inherit it. because A does not have the methods. unless you know ele default method names and create callers for them.

method 1:

```
class Ele:
    def fun(self):
        print("this is fun")


class A:
    def __init__(self, ele):
        self.ele = ele

    def fun(self):
        self.ele.fun()


ele=Ele()
a = A(ele)
a.fun()
```

method 2:

```
class Ele:
    def fun(self):
        print("this is fun")


class A(Ele):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


a = A()
a.fun()
```